# Insert into mysql table based on join result

Tags: mysql

My `MySQL` `JOIN` query works as intended:

```
SELECT subjectmie_subclasss.id AS subcl, subjectmie_classs.id AS cla, 
    subjectmie_subject.id AS subj,
    CONCAT_WS(', ' ,subjectmie_subclasss.subclasss, subjectmie_classs.classs, subjectmie_subject.subject)
    AS subjectcl        
FROM subjectmie_subclasss
INNER JOIN subjectmie_subject
    ON subjectmie_subject.id = subjectmie_subclasss.subject_id
LEFT JOIN subjectmie_classs
    ON subjectmie_classs.id = subjectmie_subclasss.classs_id;
```

However my intentions are to put these values, into a table.

Currently this was my idea of putting the results in the new table `subject_classs`:

```
INSERT INTO subject_classs
    (subject_id, classs_id, subclasss_id, subject_classs)
    SELECT subjectmie_subject.id AS subj, subjectmie_classs.id AS cla, 
        subjectmie_subclasss.id AS subcl,  
        CONCAT_WS(', ' ,subjectmie_subclasss.subclasss, subjectmie_classs.classs, subjectmie_subject.subject)
        AS subjectcl        
    FROM subjectmie_subclasss
    INNER JOIN subjectmie_subject
        ON subjectmie_subject.id = subjectmie_subclasss.subject_id
    LEFT JOIN subjectmie_classs
        ON subjectmie_classs.id = subjectmie_subclasss.classs_id;
VALUES(subj, cla, subcl, subjectcl)
```

This `QUERY` is obviously incorrect, it shows errors in `MySQL workbench` before I even execute the query so the query logic is wrong. Could someone please advise me on how to go about using `INSERT` with my `JOIN` query.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to store this result

Comment: People store different types of results for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removing the `values` clause should work:

```
INSERT INTO subject_classs
    (subject_id, classs_id, subclasss_id, subject_classs)
    SELECT subjectmie_subject.id AS subj, subjectmie_classs.id AS cla, 
        subjectmie_subclasss.id AS subcl,  
        CONCAT_WS(', ' ,subjectmie_subclasss.subclasss, subjectmie_classs.classs, subjectmie_subject.subject)
        AS subjectcl        
    FROM subjectmie_subclasss
    INNER JOIN subjectmie_subject
        ON subjectmie_subject.id = subjectmie_subclasss.subject_id
    LEFT JOIN subjectmie_classs
        ON subjectmie_classs.id = subjectmie_subclasss.classs_id;
```

Comment: Wow this is what I wanted! But I was so close I just thought `VALUES` was necessary. Thanks a lot, appreciate it.